# can't import into phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, wamp

I have a local wamp server and a live phpmyadmin/mysql via cpanel.

I am trying to import the wamp one into the live one. I have done this before without issue for different sites but this time I get

```
Create database if not exist 'test'
#1044 - Access denied for user 'c2920553'@'localhost' to database 'test'
```

My local database is called simply 'test' but my live one is called 'c2920554_test'

I am sure I am doing something wrong but I can't figure it!

Very happy to post more info if needed

Comment: *"Access denied for user"* is pretty self explanatory

Comment: **Danger**: Please be advised in stock MySQL installs 'test' is a database that all users have access to! You MUST remove the records from mysql.db if you wish to have any kind of security on that database. [Documentation Here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/default-privileges.html)

Comment: Yes. It's obvious that the user can't connect I can see that. My question us of course why

Comment: @maxelcat There are too many possible reasons why. If you research the error, and attempt some of them, it will help narrow the problem.

Comment: What is the  noumn of the MySQL live Server?...You should reconfigure your config.php when database credentials are configured

Comment: ok - that DANGER comment is most pressing - must deal with that...

Comment: I have created a new database and db user on the live server. I can import database in from AONTHER live site, but the one that is exported from my WAMP wont import. I have also tried another db from the WAMP and that wont import either. So, something to do with the way the phpmyadmin on the wamp is exporting maybe?

Answer (score 0):

I deleted out of the WAMP export the line that said

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `test` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;
USE `db-name`;
```

and now it seems to work.

I don't know why though...